# Can anyone identify the characters on this seal?

Tags: characters, character-identification, seal

I saw this seal recently visiting a friend of mine who collects old paintings and calligraphy in Shanghai. I'm hoping that someone here knows what these characters are. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Seal 1]

EDIT: Here is the full image, including the calligraphy.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the seal, my best guess is "敏之":

the left character is 㞢 (u+37a2), a variant of 之 (u+4e4b):

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=㞢](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E3%9E%A2)

the right character had a left-right structure, the right component is 攴 (攵):

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=攴](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%94%B4)

unfortunately, the left component is hard to recognise, so "敏" is my guess only.

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=敏](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%95%8F)

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I actually think your guess looks pretty close! I am wondering what this seal would be referencing. Is this a name? I apologize if this is a silly question, I am new to this area.

Comment: Also, is it possible to translate the calligraphy? I understand if it is too difficult or messy.

Comment: most likely, it’s the name of the writer. about the calligraphy, certain characters are not yet recognised, maybe later :)

Comment: The link you provided about 攴 says that 攵 might be an alternative form of 攴, but there seems to be no evidence for the converse.

Comment: @Kagrenacle the only characters I can recognise are on the second column, "丁卯年？(illegible)十二月".

Comment: @Kagrenacle also the last two on the first column might read "時鮮", which usually means "seasonal vegetables/foods". Do you know if the characters are related to these? (For example, is this calligraphy exhibited in a restaurant?)

Comment: @Vim I own the painting, but the painting next to the calligraphy appears to be of loquats and some kind of fish. So that makes sense to me.

Comment: @Kagrenacle that would be great. In that case I would make a further guess that the entire first (the **rightmost**, for what it's worth) column reads "洞庭時鮮", and the fruits and fish on the painting actually symbolise "seasonal, fresh foods" (literal meaning of "時鮮") obtained from/grown in the DongTing Lake (洞庭湖, the second largest fresh water lake in China).